# Isolating a street segment and assigning it a code

Tags: transportation, road

How should I go about making a map of alternate side of the street parking rules (in nyc?)? Does such a one already exist (I can't seem to find one)?

---

If anyone is familiar with the transportation rules in NYC, certain days of the week you cannot park on a specific side of the road because that side of the road is being cleaned. The location and time varies. But I am interested in overlaying a map of my home borough (Brooklyn) with specific street signs, and then coding them so that I can easily see "this is all the monday sides", "this is all the tuesday sides", "if I am looking for a parking spot on Wednesday I should look here and not there" etc.

To do this, I downloaded a couple of files from NYC Open Data https://data.cityofnewyork.us/ . The two primary data files I have are:

Parking Regulation Sign Locations - it stores information related to:
BoroughCode, StatusOrderNumber, SignSequence, Distance, ArrowPoints, SignDescription

And Parking Regulation Street Segements - BoroughCode, StatusOrderNumber, MainStreet    FromStreet, ToStreet, SideOfStreet.

Obviously the two tables can be joined on the basis of StatusOrderNumber. But looking at the Lion Shapefile put out by the NYC Department of City Planning, they do not keep their roads by road segments; they simply label the entire road.

My more specific question would then be:

**How would I isolate a specific road segment (IE: Flatbush between 5th avenue and 8th avenue) from a road (ie: flatbush avenue) and populate it with a specific code that says 'on wednesday, there is no parking on the east side of this road segement between 11am and 1230pm?**

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it will be difficult. THe [LION shapefile](http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/html/bytes/dwnlion.shtml) does come in individual street segments, but it is unclear if they will easily match to the current table of parking rules. Here I opened up the LION shapefile and selected the section of Flatbush you requested. Here we can see that this is contained as multiple street segments in the shapefile.

[image]

If you look at the attributes of the street segments, you will see two fields named `NodeIDFrom` and `NodeIDTo`. You can build a list of intersection names from these nodes that would be close to your MainStreet FromStreet, ToStreet variables, although if these span multiple nodes that won't even work directly. E.g. if you literally had Flatbush from 5th to 8th in the parking regulation set that would not discretely merge to the streets I highlighted in the screen shot, as they have Flatbush from 5th to 6th, Flatbush from 6th to 7th etc.

If that is the case, you might have to build a network and given the MainStreet FromStreet and MainStreet ToStreet nodes identify all of the intermediate nodes for the shortest route between them to make a set that can match to the LION shapefiles.

Comment: Thanks. As I'm looking over the parking regulations street segment file, I'm hard pressed to find a street segment which spans more than one intersection. I am going to guess then, that the file I have would not have Flatbush from 5th to 8th but Flatbush from 5th to 6th, 6th to 7th, etc.

Comment: Thats good then. You should be able to build the street intersections to match in the LION file based on the node IDs then. Use the STREET variable in the LION file for the MAINSTREET variable, and use the To and From node IDs to build the possible intersections.

Comment: It turns out that the DOT does have a well furnished map of their own that explains in a user friendly way these related issues: http://www.nyc.gov/html/dot/html/motorist/parking-regulations.shtml